# How to read custom section from web.config?

Tags: c#, iis

I am implementing some IIS module to work with web.config of application.
I already had working part of module, but I managed to read custom section from web.config.

I added the following IIS schema for my custom section to standard folder %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\schema\ :

```
<configSchema>
  <sectionSchema name="myCustomSection">
    <element name="customCollection">
        <collection addElement="customItem">            
            <attribute name="name" type="string" />
            <attribute name="path" type="string" />
        </collection>
    </element>
  </sectionSchema>
</configSchema>
```

The following XML fits to the sectionSchema:

```
<configuration>
    <myCustomSection>
      <customCollection>
        <customItem name="item1" path="D:\item1\web.config" />
        <customItem name="item2" path="D:\item2\web.config" />
        <customItem name="item3" path="D:\item3\web.config" />                   
      </customCollection>
    </myCustomSection>
...
</configuration>
```

My code can read section myCustomSection and element customCollection, but customCollection is empty =(

Code to read:

```
    [ModuleServiceMethod(PassThrough = true)]
    public PropertyBag GetAppSettings(string applicationPath)
    {
        var bag = new PropertyBag();
        var manager = this.ManagementUnit.ServerManager;
        var configurationPath = ManagementConfigurationPath.CreateApplicationConfigurationPath(ManagementUnit.ConfigurationPath.SiteName, applicationPath);
        var effectiveConfigurationPath = configurationPath.GetEffectiveConfigurationPath(ManagementScope.Server);
        var configuration = manager.GetWebConfiguration(ManagementUnit.ConfigurationMap, effectiveConfigurationPath);

        var claimsSection = configuration.GetSection("myCustomSection");
        var child = claimsSection.GetChildElement("customCollection");
        var childCollection = child.GetCollection(); //count = 0
        // var childCollection = child.GetCollection("customItem"); throw exception

        ...
        return bag;
    }
```

May someone know how to get children from collection?

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately, I passed wrong applicationPath to this function.
Moreover, there is neater code to do the same stuff:

```
var section = ManagementUnit.Configuration.GetSection("myCustomSection");
var child = sect.GetChildElement("customCollection");
var childCollection = child.GetCollection();
```

Answer (score 0):

Get raw XML From section and process that XML to get attribute values.

```
       var claimsSection = config.GetSection("myCustomSection");
        string xml = claimsSection.SectionInformation.GetRawXml();
        System.Xml.XmlDocument xDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        xDoc.LoadXml(xml);

        System.Xml.XmlNode xList = xDoc.ChildNodes[0];
        for (int i =0; i< xList.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
        {
            foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode xNodo in xList.ChildNodes[i])
            {
                Console.WriteLine((xNodo.Attributes[0].Value));

            }
        }
```

Comment: This is the last way which i will try I would like to achieve my goal by dedicated means. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Look at these once https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/net-custom-configuration-section-collection-and-elements/ http://www.abhisheksur.com/2011/09/writing-custom-configurationsection-to.html

Comment: you use class ConfigurationSection from System.Configuration library, I use ConfigurationSection from System.Web.Administration. So, System.Web.Administration.ConfigurationSection doesn't contain the SectionInformation property. I didn't try to use System.Configuration library to get configuration and section. May need to convert my section to System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection